# R : Mixed design frequency test (5 [within] x 5 [within] x 2 [between])

Tags: r

I have (taste) test results of  **two independent groups**  (between subject : young and old), and  **two dependent variables**  (within subject : correct answer and wrong answer).

I made two frequency tables (one for each group) of wrong answers (within subject : five categories) against the actual answer given by the participant (within subject : correct answer with five categories). The data is dependent within a group (young or old).

**I want to investigate whether the 'sour-salty confusion' occurs more/less frequent in young vs. old. How to test this?**

Here's my code of the freq.tables : 
('data_TS_wrong' includes all data)

> Y <- table(data_TS_wrong_Y$TTest_correct_answer,data_TS_wrong_Y$TTest_wrong_answer) 
>   O <- table(data_TS_wrong_O$TTest_correct_answer,data_TS_wrong_O$TTest_wrong_answer)
>
> Y 
>            bitter nothing salty sour sweet
>   bitter   0      0      38     6    9     1 
>   nothing  0      8       0     1    6     3 
>   salty    0      5       9     0   20     2 
>   sour     0      8      38    15    0     4 
>   sweet    0      2      20     6    4     0
>
> O 
>            bitter nothing salty sour sweet 
>   bitter   0      0      39     2    0     6 
>   nothing  0      1       0     2    1     1 
>   salty    0      3      22     0   30     1 
>   sour     0      4      38    18    0     3 
>   sweet    0      2      20     3    0     0

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce your tables to a `data.frame` then merge them:

```
 dt1 <- as.data.frame(Y)
 dt2 <- as.data.frame(O)
 merge(dt1,dt2,by=1:2)
```

Now you should get a new data.frame where you can compare Frequencies for each row.